# Custom Tensorflow operation taking a list of mutable input tensors

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow

I'm trying to program a custom Tensorflow operation in C++. This operation should take a list of tensors as input and modify their content. I thought to use the example of the Assign operation, which is registered as follows in the Tensorflow code:

```
REGISTER_OP("Assign")
    .Input("ref: Ref(T)")
    .Input("value: T")
    .Output("output_ref: Ref(T)")
    .Attr("T: type")
    ...
```

For reference, `input(0)` of the Assign operation (`ref`) is the tensor to assign to, and `input(1)` (`value`) is its new value. The output tensor (`output_ref`) is simply a reference to the `input(0)` propagated.

In its definition, the Assign operation also has the following code to check that the first input is a mutable tensor:

```
OP_REQUIRES(context, IsRefType(context->input_type(0)),
errors::InvalidArgument("lhs input needs to be a ref type"));
```

Contrary to the Assign operation, my custom operation should take a *list of mutable tensors* (rather than a single tensor) who's content will be modified by the operation.

I tried registering my operation the following way:

```
REGISTER_OP("MyCustomOperation")
    .Input("refs: list(Ref(T))")
    .Attr("T: type")
    ...
```

But when loading the library, Tensorflow gives me the following error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Reference to unknown attr 'list' from Input("refs: list(Ref(T))") for Op MyCustomOperation
```

I also tried `refs: list(T)` with the attribute `T: Ref(type)`, but this doesn't work either (Tensorflow prints the error `Trouble parsing type string at 'Ref(type)' from Attr("T: Ref(type)")`).

So I switched to the following registration:

```
REGISTER_OP("MyCustomOperation")
    .Input("refs: list(Ref(T))")
    .Attr("T: type")
    ...
```

With this definition however, the `IsRefType` assertion fails. Note that I'm passing a list of `tf.RefVariable` at Python level, which I assume are mutable.

How can I make my operation properly expect a list of mutable tensors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some investigation, I found an example of an operation that does that. Here  is the solution for passing a list of mutable tensors:

```
REGISTER_OP("MyCustomOperation")
    .Input("refs: Ref(N * T)")
    .Attr("T: type")
    .Attr("N: int")
    ...
```

Comment: Can you do the same thing for Attr?

Comment: If I read the doc comment in https://cs.opensource.google/tensorflow/tensorflow/+/master:tensorflow/core/framework/op_def_builder.h correctly, the `list(...)` syntax is meant for attrs.